# How do I shorten a discord.py close bot code with 3 people as owner?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image]

How do I make this code shorter and only so 3 people with specific uuids can do the command?

I've tried the brackets with 3 uuids separated by commas / or
it still doesn't work and this is the only solution I've found

Comment: Do not post code as images, post text using 3 backticks to format the code.

Comment: Create a list with the 3 IDs and then just check if the `message.author.id` is in this list

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```py
if ctx.message.author.id in [111111,22222222,33333333]:
```

Also in your current code `channel1` and `channel2` are only created in the first `if`, should the code go to the `else` and thise variables would be undefined.

Comment: Where should I put the variables? at the start where all my other variables are?

Comment: Since you're unifying you don't need so many `if elses`, so really only the first `if` block and the last `else`, also since it seems like the channels are always the same you can put them outside right before the `if`

Comment: alright thanks!!!